# it's possible send it app TVOS to itunes connect without the real device?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, tvos, apple-tv

I have a question...

Can I send an app from xcode to iTunes connect, without physically having the real device?

For example, I designed an app for TVOS, but I don't have an Apple TV. Can I send it to itunes connect without the actual device?
Xcode say this error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the platform “tvOS” were found.

But i don't have a apple tv os device :(

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Like iOS, it's strongly suggested to test apps on real devices, but it's not mandatory. You can send the app like you already do for iOS apps, but be sure to create a new tvOS app on iTunes Connect.

You also need certificates from Apple Developer in order to export the app for the App Store. Note that you need separate certificates for the tvOS App Store. When you create a new provisioning profile on Apple Developer, be sure to choose "tvOS App Store".

Comment: Hello there! Thank you..
And it works for me !!
I had to change the profile assignment to "none" and then return the mine. ;)

Comment: yes it is mandatory to have a physical Apple TV Device. Xcode won't allow you to upload an app without it

Comment: @SamB No, it's not mandatory. Xcode doesn't check if you tested or not an app with the physical device.